# clang-tidy readability-identifier-naming IgnoredRegexp

Tags: c++, regex, clang-tidy

I want to exclude certain regex patterns from linting for `readability-identifier-naming`.

Part of `.clang-tidy` I'm using:

```yaml
Checks: 'readability-*'
CheckOptions:
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.TypeAliasCase
    value:           CamelCase
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.TypeAliasIgnoredRegexp
    value:           '(*_type|*reference|*iterator)'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.TypedefCase
    value:           CamelCase
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.TypedefIgnoredRegexp
    value:           '(*_type|*reference|*iterator)'
```

However, warnings on those regex patterns are not suppressed.

For example,

```cpp
using value_type = T;
using reference = value_type&;
using const_iterator = const T*;
```

Is this the right way to use regex for `clang-tidy`?

Comment: Seems you use globbing syntax and not regex one... (don't know which one is expected though).

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried to use `.*` and it didn't work. I was wondering if `clang-tidy` uses POSIX or Perl's for its regex engine. I'm also not sure if I have to escape parentheses or pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [changeset](https://repo.hca.bsc.es/gitlab/rferrer/llvm-epi/-/commit/9c4df9eecb6ca6b53d919cec9b460de46dd40302) that introduced the `IgnoredRegexp` it seems you have to use a proper regex - not a glob-match in the `value`-string

```
%check_clang_tidy %s readability-identifier-naming %t -- 
  -config='{CheckOptions: [ 
    {key: readability-identifier-naming.ParameterCase, value: CamelCase}, 
    {key: readability-identifier-naming.ParameterIgnoredRegexp, value: "^[a-z]{1,2}$"}, 
    {key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase, value: CamelCase}, 
    {key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassIgnoredRegexp, value: "^fo$|^fooo$"}, 
    {key: readability-identifier-naming.StructCase, value: CamelCase}, 
    {key: readability-identifier-naming.StructIgnoredRegexp, value: "sooo|so|soo|$invalidregex["} 
 ]}'
```

See: clang-tools-extra/test/clang-tidy/checkers/readability-identifier-naming-ignored-regexp.cpp

Guessing from your question and the samples, a pattern might look like this:

```
value:           '^.*_type$|^.*reference$|^.*iterator$'
```

If you need a non-greedy version you might be out of luck since the leveraged [`llvm::Regex`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Regex.html) class is using POSIX ERE and I guess lazy matching is not supported:

```
value:           '^.*?_type$|^.*?reference$|^.*?iterator$'
```

Comment: I think there's a problem with `clang-tidy`. If I run `clang-tidy --dump-config` inside a directory that contains `.clang-tidy`, `readability-identifier-naming.*IgnoredRegexp` contains an empty sting (`''`). Even if I do not use `.clang-tidy` and directly enter config, say `clang-tidy --config='{Checks: "readability-*", CheckOptions: [{key: readability-identifier-naming.TypeAliasCase, value: CamelCase}, {key: readability-identifier-naming.TypeAliasCaseIgnoredRegexp, value: "^.+_type$"}]}'`,  this still does not suppress warnings.

Comment: It seems that `clang-tidy` I'm using (`11.0.0`) does [not support](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html) `readability-identifier-naming.*IgnoredRegexp`.

Comment: @PHD Good catch. It looks like at least version 12+ is needed to use this feature. https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html The lack of version tags on their GitLab makes it difficult for me to tell the exact version number but I don't see any point releases; so, I think this is accurate.